# Replace a long string with the sed command: Argument list too long error

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I'm trying to execute this command

```
sed -i -e "s/BASE_64/$BASE_64/" FILE_NAME
```

where `$BASE_64` is a base 64 representation of a file content.

`sed` gives me an error since the string is too long.

> Argument list too long

How is it possible to avoid this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, save the base64-encoded data in a file called, e.g., `base64.txt`.

For example:

```
base64 < originalfile > base64.txt
```

Then:

```
printf '%s\n' '/BASE64/r base64.txt' 1 '/BASE64/d' w | ed FILENAME
```

This uses `ed` to search in `FILENAME` for a line containing the string `BASE64`, insert the contents of `base64.txt` after that line, go back to the first line, then search for the line with string `BASE64` again and delete it.  The `w` command in `ed` saves the modified file.

Comment: What if `BASE64` is just part of the line though and you don't want to replace the entire line?

Comment: base64 text tends to be multi-line (**many** lines), so inserting it into the middle of a line is kind of pointless. I'd do the `/BASE64/r base64.txt` insert as above, and then `s/BASE64//` rather than `/BASE64/d`.

Comment: That may be, though one short example where it would break it to have the encoded data on the next line is if you were populating the Authorization header for an HTTP request using Basic authentication, then you'd have a short base64 encoded string that would be substituted in place, given the problem at hand though, that's probably not the situation in this case

Comment: In a case like that, a) it would be extremely unlikely to cause an "Argument list too long error" like the OP reported and b) I'd use a method more appropriate to the task at hand...a simple `s/BASE_64/$BASE_64_TEXT/` with sed or ed or perl or whatever would probably suffice.

Answer (score 12):

You could always do (since you're using GNU `sed` already (`-i`)):

```
sed -i -f - FILE_NAME << EOF
s/BASE_64/$BASE_64/g
EOF
```

`-f -` tells `sed` to read the sed script from stdin.

If you want to reuse the same script for several files, on Linux (and Linux only), with a shell like `zsh`, `ksh` and `bash` version up  to 5.0 that implements here documents with temporary files (as opposed to pipes like `dash` or `yash` (or `bash` 5.1+) for relatively small heredocs and still with GNU `sed`, you could do:

```
find . -name '*.conf' -exec sed -i -f /dev/stdin {} + << EOF
s/BASE_64/$BASE_64/g
EOF
```

On Linux (and Linux and Cygwin only), `/dev/stdin` does not mean *stdin* in the same way `-` does. Instead, it's a symlink to the file open on stdin, so each time `sed` opens it, it opens the file anew from the start. The above command would work OK on other systems (that have `/dev/stdin`) or with shells that implement here-documents with pipes but only if there are few enough `conf` files that `sed` is called only once. When called the second time, on non-Linux/Cygwin systems, like with `-f -`, `/dev/stdin` would appear empty because it has already been read by the first invocation.

`busybox` `sed` also supports `-i` in the same way as GNU `sed` does, but does not support `-f -`. So you'd want to use `-f /dev/stdin` there in any case. With FreeBSD `sed`, use:

```
sed -i '' -f /dev/stdin FILE_NAME << EOF
s/BASE_64/$BASE_64/g
EOF
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to replace `sed` with `ed` and store your commands in a file.  For example, if you create `ed_cmds` with the following contents:

```
%s/BASE_64/<expanded variable>/g
w
q
```

you could then run

```
< ed_cmds ed FILE_NAME
```

and it would make the changes you wanted, so instead of setting `$BASE_64` you'd create the ed command file.

**Ed Explanation**

- `%` means to apply the command to each line of the file
- `s/pat1/pat2/g` substitutes occurrences of `pat1` with `pat2` and `g` at the end makes it do it for every match on the line, not just the first
- `w` write the changes to disk
- `q` quit (which would happen when it got EOF anyway)

Of course, you could put your `sed` commands in a file and use `-f` as well, but if you're doing that and you want to modify the file in place you might as well use `ed` instead of creating a temporary file and moving it as `sed -i` does.

Comment: can you pls give me example for above solution I am having same issue using sed.As I am new to shell dont know how to create ed_cmds file

Answer (score 2):

The size of the Base64 representation of the file ($BASE_64) is too long and exceeds maximum argument size. You should be able to see this limit for your system by running

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

You have to increase the size of the `ARG_MAX` value. 
But I think if the file is too big, then you will have to use a different approach to do this replacement. If a Python script would do it for you, i'd try it with that too.

Comment: thanks. I will go with a Python script if there is no other solution.

Comment: Note that Linux in particular has a hard-coded limit for the length of a _single_ command line argument, so increasing `ARG_MAX` doesn't even help there.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up putting the `sed` instructions into a file

```
SEDCOMMANDS=`tempfile`
```

and called

```
sed -f "$SEDCOMMANDS" -- "$FILE_NAME"
```

That's good if you don't use `sed -i`. If you want to edit the file in place, follow https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284188/149867 and put the equivalent `ed` instructions in a file, followed by `w` and `q`.

Comment: `-i` works fine with `-f`. Only, make sure you use `-i -f` (or `-i '' -f` with BSD `sed`), not `-if`. You can also [use `-f -`](/a/347630) to avoid the temp file.

Answer (score 1):

I felt like I would share what i've done since i've read your ideas before I made my own code :

my original code :

```
local DOCUMENTCONTENT=$(base64 -w 0 $fichier)

sed -e 's&{DOCUMENTCONTENT}&'"$DOCUMENTCONTENT"'&g;s& 
{FILENAME}&'"$basename_fichier"'&g;s& 
{INTERFACETYPECODE}&'"$p_InterfaceTypeCode"'&g;s& 
{INTERFACEPARAMETERLIST}&'"$p_InterfaceParameterList"'&g;s& 
{JOBNAME}&'"$p_JobName"'&g' template_ImportOperation.json > 
ImportOperation.json
```

where $DOCUMENTCONTENT is a zip file of 3.2 Mb.(22Mb uncompressed)
sed was failing with arguments too long as well.

new code : instead of a variable, I use a file : ($fichier is my input file).
I use awk and tell it to read from my file instead of from my variable

```
base64 -w 0 $fichier > "ImportOperation.b64"

sed -e 's&{FILENAME}&'"$basename_fichier"'&g;s& 
{INTERFACETYPECODE}&'"$p_InterfaceTypeCode"'&g;s& 
{INTERFACEPARAMETERLIST}&'"$p_InterfaceParameterList"'&g;s& 
{JOBNAME}&'"$p_JobName"'&g' template_ImportOperation.json > 
ImportOperation.json.2

awk 'BEGIN { getline replacement < "ImportOperation.b64" } {gsub(" 
{DOCUMENTCONTENT}", replacement); print}' ImportOperation.json.2 > 
ImportOperation.json

rm ImportOperation.json.2
```

That may not be the cleanest of codes, but it works.
hope that helps.

Comment: I don't remember the 'sed' rules right now for line-ending, but anything that would break up the substitution into multiple lines would improve clarity and thus usefulness. There would be no measurable effect on speed. The same goes for the 'awk'.