# sed Argument List Too Long While Updating JSON

Tags: shell, sed, json

I've a JSON property which needs to be updated with base64. 
The flow is:

```
prop_val=`base64 --wrap=0 < $prop_txt`
sed -i 's@"property_specific": ""@"property_specific": "'"${prop_val}"'"@g' $final_json
```

It errors out with: `line 22: /bin/sed: Argument list too long`

The base64 string (single line) is very long. How else can I update the property w/o sed?

Note: the double quotes in format.

Update:

- Created place holder unique string, to remove double quotes complexity.
- Tried `sed -f`; didn't work.

Tried:

```
     sed -i -f - $final_json << EOF; 's@placeHolder123456@'"${prop_val}"'@g'; EOF
```

Error:

```
line 27: warning: here-document at line 23 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
line 28: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Tried placing it in a function to avoid `EOF` error, but it didnt work. Function:

```
update_prop_specific() {
    sed -i -f - $1 << EOF
    s@placeHolder123456@$2@g
    EOF
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: This answer might help you: [Replace a long string with the sed command: Argument list too long error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284170/replace-a-long-string-with-the-sed-command-argument-list-too-long-error)

Comment: @PesaThe thank you, I saw that. Here I need it to be in the same line between double quotes. It’s a good breadcrumb though.

Comment: @Simply_Me, the `sed -f - <<EOF` solution should still work, I don't think the double quotes should make a difference with that

Comment: @ilkkachu interesting, I’ll give it a try shortly.

Comment: @ilkkachu I tried it, but it errors out (see update).

Comment: @Simply_Me, the data and the delimiter to the heredoc need to be on separate lines, just putting semicolons there doesn't work. some examples: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Heredocs_And_Herestrings

Comment: @ilkkachu then the solution you pointed to doesn't apply here.

Comment: @Simply_Me, well, why? (You do already have two separate lines, the other contains the assignment to `prop_val`.) What other limitations are there?

Comment: @ilkkachu it's in a for loop, and even if if I make it a function call it will error because of other operations after the injection.

Answer (score -1):

ended up setting up another file with `sed -i -f ....` and calling it from the main script, since function and explicit calls cause `unexpected EOF`